# Empty (white) framebuffer - shadow mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shadow-mapping

See **EDIT** since the first part of the problem is solved.

I am trying to replicate the shadow mapping demo from http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping with my own framework, but interestingly I did not get any shadows. The first significant problem is that my depthmap is not correctly working. I have debugged and double checked each line without success. Maybe another pair of eyes will have more success.

See (top left, 5th row - the image is completely white): 
[image]

I will write about the second render pass, since it seems that the first one is not working. By the way, the objects are centered at 0, 0, 0. The following code is used for the first render pass:

```
/// 1. render target is the depth map
glViewport(0, 0, SHADOW_MAP_WIDTH_u32, SHADOW_MAP_HEIGHT_u32);
m_frameBufferObject.bind();    // set the depth map as render target
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
/// place the camera where the light is positioned and render the scene
math::Matrix4D l_lightViewMatrix = math::Matrix4D::lookAt(m_light_p->getPosition(), math::Vector3D(0, 0, 0), math::Vector3D(0, 1, 0));
const math::Matrix4D& l_orthographicLightMatrix_r = m_light_p->getShadowInformation().getProjectionMatrix();
math::Matrix4D lightSpaceMatrix = l_orthographicLightMatrix_r * l_lightViewMatrix;

m_depthMapShader_p->bind();
m_depthMapShader_p->setUniformMat4("lightSpaceMatrix", lightSpaceMatrix);

renderNodes();

m_depthMapShader_p->printShaderInfoLog();
m_depthMapShader_p->unbind();
m_frameBufferObject.unbind();
```

I have tested that the view matrix and projection matrix generation delivers exactly the same results as GLM (math library for opengl). However, my orthographic matrix is defined by:

```
left = -10.0f
right = 10.0f
bottom = -10.0f
top = 10.0f
near = -1.0f
far = 7.5f
```

The initialization of the framebuffer object and the texture is as follows:

```
// - Create depth texture            
glGenTextures(1, &m_shadowTextureBuffer_u32);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_shadowTextureBuffer_u32);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, SHADOW_MAP_WIDTH_u32, SHADOW_MAP_HEIGHT_u32, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

m_frameBufferObject.bind();
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_shadowTextureBuffer_u32, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on building shadow framebuffer\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
m_frameBufferObject.unbind();
```

The fragment and the vertex shader looks like below.

```
#version 430
// Fragment shader for rendering the depth values to a texture.

out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main()
{
   gl_FragColor = vec4 (gl_FragCoord.z);
}



#version 430

// Vertex shader for rendering the depth values to a texture.

in layout (location = 0) vec3 position;
in layout (location = 1) vec4 color;
in layout (location = 2) vec3 normal;
in layout (location = 3) vec2 uv;
in layout (location = 4) vec3 tangent;
in layout (location = 5) int materialId;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;
uniform mat4 vw_matrix;
uniform mat4 ml_matrix;
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = lightSpaceMatrix * ml_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

**EDIT:**

After some sleep, I have found a little error in my renderer and the shader draws a "nice" depth map.
[image]
However, it looks like that the texture mapping (depth comparison) is in the same coordinate system.

But the second rendering step is still not correct:
[image]

The vertex and the fragment shader for the second render pass looks like

```
#version 430

in layout (location = 0) vec3 position;
in layout (location = 1) vec4 color;
in layout (location = 2) vec3 normal;
in layout (location = 3) vec2 uv;
in layout (location = 4) vec3 tangent;
in layout (location = 5) int materialId;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix = mat4(1.0);

out VS_OUT
{
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texture_coordinates;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 tangent;
    vec3 binormal;
    vec3 worldPos;
    vec4 shadowProj;
    flat int materialIdOut;
} vs_out;

void main()
{
    vs_out.color = color;
    vs_out.texture_coordinates = uv;

    mat3 normalMatrix = transpose ( inverse ( mat3 ( ml_matrix )));
    vs_out.normal = normalize ( normalMatrix * normalize ( normal ));
    vs_out.tangent = normalize ( normalMatrix * normalize ( tangent ));
    vs_out.binormal = normalize ( normalMatrix * normalize ( cross (normal , tangent )));
    vs_out.worldPos = ( ml_matrix * vec4 ( position, 1)).xyz;
    vs_out.materialIdOut = materialId;
    vs_out.shadowProj = ( lightSpaceMatrix * ml_matrix * vec4 (position, 1.0) );

    gl_Position = ( pr_matrix * vw_matrix * ml_matrix ) * vec4 (position, 1.0);
}
```

and

```
#version 430

#define MAX_NUM_TEXTURES 5
#define MAX_NUM_MATERIALS 12

struct SMaterial 
{
    vec3 m_ambient_v3;
    vec3 m_diffuse_v3;
    vec3 m_specular_v3;    
    float m_shininess_f32;
    int m_textureIds[MAX_NUM_TEXTURES];
}; 

in VS_OUT 
{
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texture_coordinates;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 tangent;
    vec3 binormal;
    vec3 worldPos;
    vec4 shadowProj;
    flat int materialIdOut;
} fs_in;

uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform mat4 ml_matrix;
uniform mat4 vw_matrix;
uniform sampler2D texSlots[32];

uniform SMaterial material[MAX_NUM_MATERIALS];
uniform SLight light;

out vec4 gl_FragColor;

float shadowCalculation(vec4 fragPosLightSpace)
{
    // perform perspective divide
    vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
    // Transform to [0,1] range
    projCoords = projCoords * vec3(0.5) + vec3(0.5);
    // Get closest depth value from light's perspective (using [0,1] range fragPosLight as coords)
    float closestDepth = texture(texSlots[31], projCoords.xy).r; 
    // Get depth of current fragment from light's perspective
    float currentDepth = projCoords.z;
    // Check whether current frag pos is in shadow
    float shadow = currentDepth > closestDepth  ? 1.0 : 0.0;

    return shadow;
}

void main()
{
    if ( (fs_in.materialIdOut >= 0) && (fs_in.materialIdOut < MAX_NUM_MATERIALS) )
    {
        int ambientTextureId = material[fs_in.materialIdOut].m_textureIds[0];
        int diffuseTextureId = material[fs_in.materialIdOut].m_textureIds[1];
        int specularTextureId = material[fs_in.materialIdOut].m_textureIds[2];
        int alphaTextureId = material[fs_in.materialIdOut].m_textureIds[3];
        int bumpTextureId = material[fs_in.materialIdOut].m_textureIds[4];

        vec3 diffTexColor = vec3(0.6,0.6,0.6);
        if ((diffuseTextureId >= 0) && (32 > diffuseTextureId))
        {
            diffTexColor = texture (texSlots[diffuseTextureId], fs_in.texture_coordinates).rgb;
        }

        // Calculate shadow
        float shadow = 1.0 - shadowCalculation(fs_in.shadowProj);       
        gl_FragColor = vec4(diffTexColor, 1.0) * vec4(shadow, shadow, shadow, 1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(fs_in.normal,1.0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience a depth map is pretty much always completely white, because a distance of more than 1 away from the light already makes that pixel white. If your whole scene is further than 1 unit then the whole map is white.

To render the map like they show in the tutorial you either need your scene to be really small or to perform an operation on your depth map. I always like to check my maps by dividing their depth values by the camera's zFar distance. Try to find the best value at which you can see contrast.

Comment: The default depth range is [0.0, 1.0]. Nothing in the depth buffer would be > 1.  I get the impression you're talking about storing actual eye-space z, rather than depth.